# IIS Rewrite module, simple rule

Tags: iis, rewrite

I am stuck on a very simple IIS rewrite rule.  I have a series of links that have an invalid path, and I need to redirect all requests to that path to a new one.

Here is the broken path:  https://documentation.buzsoftware.com/buzdocs/BuzClubManager/index.cfm?ID=690

The "buzdocs" portion of the path no longer exists and all links below this path have been moved up one folder to this example path (which works):  https://documentation.buzsoftware.com/BuzClubManager/index.cfm?ID=690

```
<rule name="buzdocs_path_del" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)/buzdocs(.*)" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}{R:2}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

or

```
<rule name="buzdocs_path_del" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="https://documentation.buzsoftware.com/buzdocs(.*)" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="https://documentation.buzsoftware.com/{R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

I have been trying a wide variety of regex patterns, and every time I go to the incorrect path I get a 404, and I am not redirected.

I'm not sure if I need to use the ^ (start of line) or $ (end of line) in the pattern match, I've tried both with the same result.

Using only the {R:1} (first example) vs. using both {R:1} and {R:2} (second example), not sure which is the right way.  Any comments on best practices would be helpful.

I've also bounced back and forth between `<action type="Rewrite"`  and `<action type="Redirect"`, with no change.

These links are to a live site, feel free to hit them.  Thanks for any advise, I'm pretty sure I'm missing something small, and I will probably hit my head on my desk for it.

Comment: https://blog.lextudio.com/the-very-common-mistakes-when-using-iis-url-rewrite-module-a2ab7e4fee59 Mistake 1.